# Time Series Analysis to find a particular date based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe `badges`. The `Class` column has the level of the badge `(1=Gold, 2=Silver, 3=Bronze)`. I want to get the time when the user with `UserId = '699'` got his first silver medal. I tried the given code but I am getting a KeyError. Please help me fix this.

**DataFrame**

```
   Id | UserId |  Name          |        Date              |Class | TagBased
   2  | 23     | Autobiographer | 2016-01-12T18:44:49.267  |   3  | False
   3  | 22     | Autobiographer | 2016-01-12T18:44:49.267  |   3  | False
   4  | 21     | Autobiographer | 2016-01-12T18:44:49.267  |   3  | False
   5  | 20     | Autobiographer | 2016-01-12T18:44:49.267  |   3  | False
   6  | 19     | Autobiographer | 2016-01-12T18:44:49.267  |   3  | False
```

**Code**

```
test_silver = badges[badges.Date.loc[badges.UserId=='699']]
min(test_silver)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean indexing (like you already did) and then `head` to extract the first record:

```
badges.loc[badges.UserId.eq('699') & badges.Class.eq(2), 'Date'].head(1)
```

Comment: I tried this but got a `TypeError: dtype: bool, 'Date')' is an invalid key`.

Comment: @IshanDutta sorry, forgot the `.loc` :-)